# Error in loading "GaltonFamilies" dataframe in R - object not found

Tags: r

I am using the following code to get a set of heights sampled from `GaltonFamilies`

```
set.seed(1989, sample.kind="Rounding") 
library(HistData)
data("GaltonFamilies")

female_heights <- GaltonFamilies%>%     
    filter(gender == "female") %>%     
    group_by(family) %>%     
    sample_n(1) %>%     
    ungroup() %>%     
    select(mother, childHeight) %>%     
    rename(daughter = childHeight)
```

But then I get the following error:

```
"Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : object 'GaltonFamilies' not found"
```

Any ideas on what could be going on?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. Are you sure you don't get any errors/warnings from the firs three lines? It seems like you are just not loading the dataset into your global environment. Does `ls()` return "GaltonFamilies" after you run the `data()` command? What version of `HistData` are you using?

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for the tip, I am now getting a new error: "Error in filter(., gender == "female") : object 'gender' not found". Any ideas on this one?

Comment: You seem to be trying to use `dplyr` functions. Did you load that library as well? It's not in the code you've shared. What does `names(GaltonFamilies)` return.

Comment: @MrFlick Ah I forgot the dplyr. Thanks so much, it's working now!